# Change the version automatically using Gradle Release plugin

Tags: spring, git, gradle

I would like to have a new version on every commit in the master branch.

Since I'm using gradle to build, I found 2 nice plugins, Release https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release/issues/273 and Git Versioner https://github.com/passsy/gradle-gitVersioner-plugin.

I would like to manage daily commits with some version like 1.0.0.BuildNumber. This needs to create a tag in Git and push, but also I need to set the project.version tag with the right version because I need it for the springBoot buildInfo (I'm getting the BuildProperties in Spring to know the version I'm executing on).

When I try to run:

```
gradlew release -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true
```

It always fall back to 0.0.1 version.

I'm just using the default configuration of the plugin and I got lost ...

Answer (score 0):

I still had the old project.version defined and the plugin was defaulting to that one.